# JavaFX: An object created in a method and used in another class?

Tags: java, javafx-2

I am theoretically not new on Java, but a beginner on practice.
I am experimenting with `JavaFX` and to begin with, I am implementing a `GUI` where the window (`Stage`) has the **size of the screen**.

**The problem**: I want to use this `screen size object`  which is type of `Rectangle` and named `screenBorders` in **another class**(called `Second`).
Here is my simple code:

```
public class Test extends Application 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { launch(args);}

    public static Rectangle screenBorders;

     @Override
     public void start(Stage primaryStage) 
     {
      Group grp=new Group();
      Scene sc = new Scene(grp);
      primaryStage.setScene(sc);
      primaryStage.show();

      screenBorders= new Rectangle (
      Screen.getPrimary().getBounds().getWidth(),
      Screen.getPrimary().getBounds().getHeight()
      );

      Second second= new Second();

     }

}
```

**New file, new class**

```
class Second extends Group
{

   public Second () 
   {
    Rectangle second =new Rectangle(screenBorders.getWidth(), screenBorders.getHeight());
   }
//code, code, code, don't know yet what code i will put...
}
```

In this second class, I can't catch/use the `screensize` defined in the first class.( I want to use `screenBorders`)

I've tried to declare `screenBorders` with `public` and `static` keyword in the first and main class called `Test`, thinking that it could be used **anywhere in my package**, but it does'not work.

Does anyone have an idea about how to **link** an object with other classes ?

Comment: "but it doesn’t work" can you please what's the problem or the error that you get.

Comment: It says the "cannot find symbol" error, but it's been resolved by an import static as shown below. thks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access static variable from `Second` class you need to either state first class name directly:

```
Rectangle second = new Rectangle(
    Test.screenBorders.getWidth(), 
    Test.screenBorders.getHeight());
```

**or** use import static at the beginning of `Second` class:

```
import static Test.*;
```

Comment: user2305415, I should add, that this solution could be not the one you want, because, if size of stage will change, you will get nonotification about that. So, instead of making Rectangle staticly available, try to make Screen.getPrimary().boundsProperty() staticly available, and bind smth to the widthProperty() and heightProperty() of the bounds property().

Comment: @Sergey Grinev I've used the second method "import static Test.*;" and it works !!! Thanks !! :)

Comment: @AlexanderKirov don"t really understand the difference, but maybe i'll have to try your property() method :) thks

Comment: I don't know about your application, but the difference is the fact, that when you create a rectangle, it will have fixed values, as they were in the moment of initialization. But when you use properties and bindings, you will have access to the newest and the most actual values at any time.

Comment: @AlexanderKirov Humm i see.. so there is kind of two cases : 1-If the rectangle's dimensions have to keep the same across the whole application, so there's no need for any properties and bindings as you said. 2-If the rectangle has to change dynamically across the application, then the pair properties-bindings would for sure be necessary. In my case, i want the rectangle remains exactly as the same during all the application,so i think case 1 is more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Stage.setFullScreen(true)`, documentation is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#setFullScreen%28boolean%29).

Comment: I already have tried the setFullScreen() function, it sets well the window on a full screen mode but there is a sort a popup message saying that you can exit the mode with esc button, and that thing is not really appropriate for my application.